# Is there a way to summarize and join in one step with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains information about a model, a subtype and some additional data. In this example, the subtypes are only 1 and 2. In further analysis, I need only the data of models that have both subtypes.

My Goal ist to receive a list containing all values for A and B (i.e. model, type and additional_cell) but no data for C (because only model 1 is available)

My solution so far: use summarize(n_distinct) to detect if both subtypes are available if true filter those and re-join the old data-frame to get back the additional cells. In Code:

```
test = data.frame(model=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), type=c(1,2,1,2,1), additional_cell=c(10,10,10,10,10))
test %>% 
  group_by(model) %>% 
  summarise(both_types = n_distinct(type)) %>% 
  filter(both_types==2) %>% 
  left_join(test, by="model") %>% 
  select(-both_types)
```

This works but to me it looks overengineered and I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

[Edit:]
Main question is: how can I avoid the additional join, which make this question different from the suggested duplicate. Anyhow: The given answer fits my Needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be shortened to:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(model) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(type) == 2)
```